# Error with a dispatch

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is a little bit of my code where i get the error:

```
jsonTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

dispatch_async(kQueue, [?] (key only works on mac) {
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl:kJSONUrl];
```

where the dispatch gets its data from is

```
#define kQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE­_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define kJSONUrl [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dev.cas.yt/workspace/ccapp backend/schedule/students/student/week"]
```

the error is: use of unideclared identifier 'DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT'

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?
What exactly is your source code? (`[?] (key only works on mac)` is not valid source code)

Comment: the error is use of unideclared identifier 'DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT'

Comment: Please add the error to your question not as a comment under it people will not read that. Also this has absolutely nothing to do with the `xcode IDE` so don't use that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually i ended this project,

Thanks everyone who helped me